# Facebook FB.ui empty response on method: 'send'

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, fb.ui

I need to send a message to a user friend containing a custom picture and link.

This is my code:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'send',
    name: 'Name',
    link: 'http://www.example.com',
    picture: 'http://www.example.com/picture.jpg',
    description: 'Description'
    }, requestCallback
);  

function requestCallback (response) {
    console.log(response);
}
```

My problem is that the response is always empty ([ ]). I need to know which friends the user selected to send the message.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: this it heavily outdated, please disregard.

My answer is not exactly answering your question, but you can at least check if the user shared something or not : as far as I've seen it, if the user clicks on "cancel", the response won't be empty but NULL. If he shares it, the answer is an empty array.

Comment: As of now, this does not seem correct any more. I just tried to check if the user clicked cancel or shared something, but in both cases, an empty array is returned. Very confusing!

Comment: Confusing indeed - share and cancel result in an empty array, and hitting the 'X' or close on the window results in 'undefined'.

Comment: Yeah I guess this is completely outdated.

Answer (score 0):

As I know you can't get the selected users from an UI 'send' method, myself I used the 'apprequests' method to select user's friends.

Maybe you could select the targeted users with the apprequest box then prefill the selected user in the FB.ui send call like this :

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'send',
    to:'[SELECTED USER IDS]',
    name: 'Name',
    link: 'http://www.example.com',
    picture: 'http://www.example.com/picture.jpg',
    description: 'Description'
    }, requestCallback
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't use 'apprequests' because I need to show a custom picture and link.

Comment: That partially works, because the "to" field in the message is not read-only, so the user can add new friends and i won't know :(

Comment: yeah that's right, the user may do that. That's the best way I found for now. In my case It didn't matter. Maybe you could try to access to popup CSS and try to disable the "to" field but it sounds like Hacksort.

Comment: I think there is no way to get working what I need. Either way, thanks for your help and cooperation.